# How to receive a real object in GraphQL dotnet client app?

Tags: c#, graphql-dotnet

I run a GraphQL client and send the queries

```
        var response3 = await client2.SendQueryAsync<ADescriptorResponse2>(request2);
        var response2 = await client2.SendQueryAsync<dynamic>(request2);
        var response1 = await client2.SendQueryAsync<object>(request2);
```

There is

```
   public class ADescriptorResponse2
    {
        public ADescriptor aDescriptor { get; set; }
    }
    public class ADescriptor
    {
        public long  Action { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
```

But in the 1st case
var response3 = await client2.SendQueryAsync(request2);
i receive the response3.Data ==null, type ADescriptorResponse2
In other both cases I receive Data correct but it isNewtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject type.
Why I do not receive the Data of ADescriptorResponse2 filled with data?
What is incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This most probably means that the structure of the data is such that it cannot correctly deserialize to type of `ADescriptorResponse2`.

You can check the structure of the data which you get from response2 and response1 and see if it is in the shape of `ADescriptorResponse2`.

It could be some nested object issue where you need another object on top of `ADescriptorResponse2` or something of that nature.